# Как вычесть массивы пользователей

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

У меня есть список исключений с id пользователей, как мне вычесть этот список со списка всех id участников беседы?

```
exceptions = ["12345678", "013466734", "12454323455"] # список исключений
user = vk.method("messages.getConversationMembers", {"peer_id": peer_id})
ids = user['profiles']
random_u = random.choice(ids)
id = random_u['id']
```

Comment: преобразуйте списки в сеты и вычтите

Comment: А конкретней, как их преобразовать?

Comment: set1 = set(lst)

Comment: спасибо тебе :)